# Avoid deploying Cassandra as a full mesh

Tags: cassandra

We would like to use Cassandra for our distributed configuration management.

Our deployment is in a “tree” structure.
I.e. We have a single central management data center (EMS) that should “see” all the managed data centers (SDCA, DSCB, SDCC...).
Each one of the managed data centers should see its own data only, and may not see the data of the other managed data centers (SDCA for example does not need to see SDCB’s data).

In a matter of networking, the managed data centers are not connected directly to each other, but only via the central data center (EMS).

```
            +------+
            | EMS  |
            +------+
                |
                |
    +-----------+-----------+
    |           |           |
    |           |           |
+--------+   +-------+   +-------+
| SDC-A  |   | SDC-B |   | SDC-C |  ...
+--------+   +-------+   +-------+
```

Is this structure possible to implement with Cassandra, or does Cassandra enforces a full mesh between all its nodes?

Answer (score 1):

You can control the location of data in Cassandra via the keyspace definitions.

For data you only want stored in SDC-A, you would create a keyspace like this:

```
CREATE KEYSPACE SDCA WITH replication = {'class': 'NetworkTopologyStrategy', 'SDC-A': '1'};
```

Then you would create tables in keyspace SDCA and any data inserted into those tables would only be stored in the data center named SDC-A.  And the nice thing is that clients can connect to any node in the whole cluster to do those inserts, and Cassandra will route the data to SDC-A and not store it in any other data centers.

So for your example you could create four keyspaces, with one for each data center, and you would use the desired keyspace whenever you inserted data.

Or you could create three keyspaces where each keyspace replicates data to both EMS and one of the SDC's.  But you'd need to be careful if you replicated everything in A/B/C to EMS since it would have three times the data load in EMS.

Now if you don't actually want to replicate the data in A/B/C to EMS, then you can still query the data from nodes in EMS since Cassandra will just contact the nodes in the requested keyspace to get the data.  The downside of that is there will be more latency to access a remote data center.

But this assumes you have connectivity between all your data centers, so if A/B/C cannot talk to each other you won't be able to take advantage of Cassandra multi-data center support in this way.

Comment: Thanks. Well, the main problem is that indeed we don't have connectivity between A, B and C. We did use CREATE KEYSPACE SDCA WITH replication = {'class': 'NetworkTopologyStrategy', 'SDC-A': 2,'EMS':2 };. SDC-A is connected to EMS, and the other connections to SDC-B and SDC-C does not exist, but they are irrelevant anyway. But is this keyspace suppose to work correctly under the given conditions?

Comment: If SDC-A and EMS have network connectivity, then you can put them in the same cluster and replicate across them as separate DC's.  But Cassandra assumes every node has direct connectivity to all the other nodes and won't figure out that there are multi-hop routes.  So I don't think you can put B/C in that cluster since A/B/C don't have direct connectivity between them.  You might need to set B/C up as independent clusters that you address separately in your application.